# Resources for learning how to use ajax with asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a few asp.net mvc books (asp.net mvc in action, professional asp.net mvc) and they each have a chapter on ajax.  They offer a good overview but I am joining a project where it is used extensively, and I am familiar with ASP.NET but not really ajax at all.  I have looked at a few books on asp.net ajax but the examples they use don't fit with the MVC paradigm.

Can someone recommend 1) a great resource for learning jquery/another ajax library (looking to learn the fundamentals) and 2) resources for learning to use this along with asp.net mvc?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some good resources to help get you started:

**With .NET Specifically:**

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx#introduction

http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AjaxJQuerySample.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/IntegratingAJAX.aspx

**General AJAX:**

http://ajaxian.com/by/topic/ajax

http://sixrevisions.com/ajax/ajax_techniques/